# Direct convert "mkv" to "wav" using python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, wav, moviepy, mkv

How can I **directly** convert an "mkv" file to a "wav" file? It means that my goal is to extract the audio of a movie file using python. What is the process of this?

Can anybody help me with how I can do it?

My Python version is 3.10.8 and I guess it is possible with ffmpeg or moviepy. I have tried converting "mkv" to "mp4" and then extracting the audio as "wav", but I want to know is there any direct way to do this task?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) Please [edit] your question and post your code. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service.

Comment: @MattDMo Please read the last paragraph again!